# How to group by month off a timestamp field from Redshift in Superset

Tags: amazon-redshift, apache-superset

I am trying to show some trend over month in Superset from a table which has a timestamp field called `created_at` but have no idea how to get it right.

[image: Here is what I am seeing]

The SQL query generated from this is the followings:

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS __timestamp,
  SUM(cost) AS "SUM(cost)"
FROM xxxx_from_redshift
WHERE created_at >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND created_at <= '2018-07-25 20:42:13'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
ORDER BY "SUM(cost)" DESC
LIMIT 50000;
```

Like I mentioned above, I don't know how to make this work and 2nd question is why `ORDER BY` is using `SUM(cost)`? If this is a time-series, shouldn't it use `ORDER BY 1` instead? I tried to change `Sort By` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite silly but I found that SUM(cost) doesn't work while sum(cost) works. It is a bug in Superset and will be addressed in https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/5487